MouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent
I'm not great at Javascript, so typescript is an even bigger struggle for me.
I'm trying to borrow this code so I can implement an event calendar in an angular app.
.subscribe((mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
    const minutesDiff = ceilToNearest(
      mouseMoveEvent.clientY - segmentPosition.top,
      30
    );

    const daysDiff =
      floorToNearest(
        mouseMoveEvent.clientX - segmentPosition.left,
        segmentPosition.width
      ) / segmentPosition.width;

    const newEnd = addDays(addMinutes(segment.date, minutesDiff), daysDiff);
    if (newEnd > segment.date && newEnd < endOfView) {
      dragToSelectEvent.end = newEnd;
    }
    this.refresh();
  });

I get this as an error:

Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer> | ((value: Event) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer> | ((value: Event) => void) | undefined'.
Type '(mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Event) => void'.
Types of parameters 'mouseMoveEvent' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 23 more.
Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: ((value: Event) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event) => void'.
Types of parameters 'mouseMoveEvent' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'

I "sort of" understand that the types don't match, but I don't know how to change the code to make it functional.
Here is the site I'm attempting to borrowing the code from
https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/implement-angular-calendar-component
Can someone with much better typescript skills than me please help?

You should probably add a filter that filters for mouse events, then subscribe to that observable.

Just replace MouseEvent with Event, since that is the type received at the final subscribe!

Type '(mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Event) => void'

.subscribe((mouseMoveEvent: Event) => { // <- changed here!
    const minutesDiff = ceilToNearest(
      mouseMoveEvent.clientY - segmentPosition.top,
      30
    );

    const daysDiff =
      floorToNearest(
        mouseMoveEvent.clientX - segmentPosition.left,
        segmentPosition.width
      ) / segmentPosition.width;

    const newEnd = addDays(addMinutes(segment.date, minutesDiff), daysDiff);
    if (newEnd > segment.date && newEnd < endOfView) {
      dragToSelectEvent.end = newEnd;
    }
    this.refresh();
  });


That removed the overload error.  Now I'm getting: Property 'clientY' does not exist on type 'Event'

from a basic code perspective, maybe I'm not understanding the syntax (what's going on).  Does mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent mean that it's calling the class mouseMoveEvent which MouseEvent.clientY is a part of?
